# jQuery: Scroll to element in RWD website

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, anchor

I've been researching this topic for 2 days now, and I can't come up with the idea of how to solve it. The page is responsive and I want to scroll the page to certain element on load. I had it working on a desktop version using this code:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.thank-you').offset().top - 80 });
```

The 80px is the difference I need to subtrack from a stick-on-top menu bar.

The whole code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        if( $(window).width() <= 600 ){ //Mobile width      
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.thank-you').offset().top - 260});
        // $('.thank-you') is the the div that contains the thank you message
        }else{
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.thank-you').offset().top - 80 });
            }
    });
```

Now I do have problem with tablet and mobile versions - depending on a width of viewport **the element I'm scrolling to ends up being on different levels** - between 300px and 200px from the top. Right now I've set arbitrarily 260, but this gives different results and not always the good ones. [Here's the image that illustrates the problem.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47515928/thankYouPage.jpg)

The second problem is that **if the page is scrolled to the bottom before reloading, the scrolling begins from the top to the mentioned element**, so we go from the bottom to the top and then to the point in the middle of the page, which doesn't make sense.
 I've checked all possible questions I found on the Stack, I've check many solutions on the web (including Chris Coyer Css tips and tricks website). There is something weird going on with getting height of elements via element.height() method - it doesn't give the right answer - I confronted those with that Firebug shows, and these are never the same. So using simple subtraction is not an answer either.

I'll really appreciate any suggestions as to how to deal with this.